# Negative Binomial Deviance Calculation in H2O

Tags: glm, h2o

I've been looking at the deviance calculation for negative binomial model in H2O  ([code](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-algos/src/main/java/hex/glm/GLMModel.java) line 580/959) and I'm struggling to reason why it is 0 when yr or ym is/are 0.

```
(yr==0||ym==0)?0:2*((_invTheta+yr)*Math.log((1+_theta*ym)/(1+_theta*yr))+yr*Math.log(yr/ym))
```

The formula for the deviance calculation is as below (from [H2O Documentation](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/glm.html#negative-binomial)):

[image]

Going with maths, I don't see the deviance is 0 unless both yr and ym are 0.

Does anyone happen to know if there is a special case where deviance for negative binomial needs to be set to 0 when either of the yr and ym is/are 0?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it seems to me they maybe just chose the lazy way out of a numerical difficulty.

`mu=0` (`ym`) is a degenerate case where `p=0` and so `y=0` always. It's not interesting, and not really part of any useful analysis. I'm not sure it can even come out with the linear-predictor. With using the natural parameter = linear predictor, you need the linear predictor to be equal to minus infinity...

However, `y` can be equal to `0` for other `mu`'s. And what you do in this case, is take the limit of the deviance as `y->0`, which is completely defined for Negative-Binomial, and isn't equal to 0. They could have implemented it, but chose not too, so this is why I call it "lazy".